# How to change default Network timeout value for QT Online installers

Tags: qt, frameworks, installation

I'm using QT Installer Framework and I have scripts to check for updates on the online repository (I don't use the --check-updates switch since it doesn't return all the information I need).

Everything works perfectly but I have an issue when the Repository is offline. My script can takes up to 45 seconds when fetching the remote repository before returning the following error:

Network error while downloading \"http://xxx/Updates.xml?331668108\": Connection timed out

I would like to be able to set the default timeout value to a lower value so my script doesn't wait that much if there is no Internet or if the Repo is offline.

Is there a way to change the default Network timeout value for the QT Installer (ideally with the Controller Script)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Matt.